# parameterized constructor with dynamic array of object

Tags: c++

In the below program i have used two classes , and i am trying to relate the with aggregation, i have declare class A as private in class B, and with the help of constructor i am initizing base address of class A object to private member of class B object that is (A object). i am trying to pass the class A  values to class B usng parametrized constructor, but i am getting garbage values like,

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void create (B * &obj2, int siz)
{
    std::cout << obj2[0].get_nn ();     //this will run fine
    for (int i = 0; i < siz; i++)
        obj2[i] = B (10, "pranjal");    //this will also run fine

    std::cout << obj2[0].get_nn ();
}
// same line printing again, this will not give output
// *************************************** 

void display ()
{
    std::cout << object.get_data () << object.get_stringdata ();
}

// giving garbage values
// why is it happening
// *********************************program
// ************************************** enter code here
// Online C++ compiler to run C++ program online

class A {
    int rool;
    string name;
  public:
    A () { };
    A (int a, string name);
    int get_data () {
        return rool;
    }
    string get_stringdata () {
        return this->name;
    }
};

A::A (int a, string name)
{
    this->rool = a;
    this->name = name;
}

void getdetails (A * obj)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        obj[i] = A (20, "pranjal");
}

class B {

    int bbb;
    string name;
    A object;
  public:
    B () {};
    B (A s) {
        object = s;
    }
    string get_nn () {
        return object.get_stringdata ();
    }
    B (int a, string b);

    void display () {
        std::cout << object.get_data () << object.get_stringdata ();
    }
};

void dis (B * obj2)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        obj2[i].display ();
    }
}

void create (B * &obj2, int siz)
{
    std::cout << obj2[0].get_nn ();
    for (int i = 0; i < siz; i++)
        obj2[i] = B (10, "pranjal");

    std::cout << obj2[0].get_nn () << "sd";
}

B::B (int a, string b)
{
    bbb = a;
    name = b;
}

int main ()
{
    A *obj = new A[3];
    getdetails (obj);
    
    B *obj2 = new B[3];
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        obj2[i] = B (obj[i]);
    }

    create (obj2, 3);
    dis (obj2);
    obj2->display ();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your garbage values appear to be code. Is this correct or a cut and paste mistake?

Comment: In `create`, I don't think `delete[] obj2;` is a good idea. It seems counter productive.

Comment: ohh sorry i was just trying the changes in program, if icomment that delete[] obj2, then  too i am getting garbage value

Comment: pranjal  sd 846122816  846122816  846122816   ai am getting this output,  instead it should print pranjal   , plz help

Comment: Please review and [edit] your question to remove the comments from the code (or make them proper comments). See also our [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: When this assignment takes place `obj2[i]=B(obj[i]);` the values are indeterminate.

Comment: this is working fine actually, but second parameterized constructor is giving problem, by assiggning values to obj2[i]=B(10,"pranjal");   my A object variable data, which i assiged to obj2[j] is gettting vanished and giving garbage,     plz suggest me what do i do?

Comment: Side note: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice (this actually applies for *all* namespaces...).

Comment: Side note 2: You should get used to use constructor's initialiser list (not to be confused with `std::initializer_list`), it should look like `A::A(int a, string name) : rool(a), name(name) { }` (analogously for those of B), and your default constructor leaves `rool` uninitialised. Be aware that there are types that *only* can be initialised that way (references, `const` members, non-assignable types, ...).

Comment: I changed the it accordingly you told but still not working

Comment: Side note 3: No need for reference to pointer as parameter for `create` function: You get one indirection by the pointer already, and you do not intend to modify the pointer that is *passed* to the function. Thus: `void create(B* obj, size_t size)` – the correct type to specify sizes is `size_t`, by the way...

Comment: yeah i did that way also but no effect :(

Comment: @pranjal Side notes, i. e. unrelated to actual problem ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `create`, you **fully replace** the previous B objects with brand new ones using the 2 parameters constructor... which just leaves the A object member default initialized.

What could be done to fix?

1. Pass the parameters of B to A ctor:

   ```
    B::B (int a, string b): object(a, b)
    {
        bbb = a;
        name = b;
    }
   ```

   That way you initialize the `A object` member with the same parameters as its parent
2. Reset the `A object member` to its previous value:

   ```
    void create (B * &obj2, int siz)
    {
        std::cout << obj2[0].get_nn ();     //this will run fine
        for (int i = 0; i < siz; i++) {
            A old = obj2[i].object;
            obj2[i] = B (10, "pranjal");    //this will also run fine
            obj2[i].object = old;
        }
        std::cout << obj2[0].get_nn ();
    }
   ```

   But as it requires accesses to private members, `create` should be declared `friend` in `B` class:

   ```
    class B {
        ...
        friend void create (B * &obj2, int siz);
    };
   ```

Answer (score 0):

```
void create(B *&obj2,int siz)
{
    std::cout<<obj2[0].get_nn();      //this will run fine
    for(int i=0;i<siz;i++)
        obj2[i]=B(10,"pranjal");
    std::cout<<obj2[0].get_nn(); // same line printing again, this will not give output
}
```

Of course it won't: `B(int, std::string)` does not call a constructor of `A` explicitly, so `A`'s default constructor is called. This implicitly calls `name`'s default constructor, too, which will create an *empty* string.

For a similar reason you get garbage values: Your default constructor does not assign a value to `rool`, thus leaves it uninitialised; it will remain at the value that was there in memory before, which ever it was, which is what you consider 'garbage'.

This occurs because with `obj2[i] = B(10,"pranjal")` a new object is created and then copied into the target object (with optimisations, can be created directly in place, but obviously you cannot rely on).

Fix your constructor of `A` to assign a value to `rool` and the problem should go away. You might chose a non-zero value to have a more clearly visible effect:

```
A() : rool(1977) { }
```

Alternatively you can provide provide a default value to rool (requires C++11):

```
int rool = 1977;
```

That can be convenient especially if you have a larger number of constructors.

In general: You should not leave primitive types of *any* of your objects uninitialised to avoid similar problems.